# A custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-controls, custom-keyboard, android-custom-keyboard

Does anyone know how to create on Android custom keyboard with buttons "Attach file" and "Send message". It must have the same mechanic as in most popular chat messengers: Viber, Telegram. Thanks.

[image]

Viber keyboard: http://prntscr.com/odoaff

Comment: Your screenshots do not show a custom keyboard. They show an `ImageView` of a paperclip, what presumably is an `EditText` (with a "Click here to write new message"  hint), and an `ImageView` or `ImageButton` for the send button.

Comment: It should be like in Viber, Telegram or close to any messanger.

Comment: As CommonsWare already said, that's not a keyboard. That's merely a view that gets pushed up when the keyboard is shown. More precisely, that has NOTHING to do with the keyboard. Any view can be pushed up by it. Google a bit

Comment: http://prntscr.com/odoaff

Answer (score 0):

I found what I want here, it also is chat messanger: https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui